# How do you get the java file to read a number from a txt file?

Tags: java

I'm setting up a PIN verification with a hash value however no matter the input the PIN is being verified even when incorrect. I'm a bit lost as this is my first program.

I have tried implementing if statements which are there now, have also tried do/while. Not sure what I'm doing, thought I had the correct conditionals for the if statements. I also don't think my file is reading the txt file and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
public class ATMApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File balances = new File("Balances.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your PIN");
        int pin = input.nextInt();
        long A = 2654435761 L;
        long hashPin = (pin * A) % (2 * 32);

        if (hashPin == A) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your correct PIN:" + " ");
            pin = input.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

This is the idea, if the PIN is correct the program will continue however if not correct will ask for the pin again. The pin for the task is 2522. The Balances file number is 2927942074.

This is what the output should look like, I've added Access Granted to see if it is going to work.
Please enter your PIN: 2000
Please enter your correct PIN: 2522

Comment: what does any of this has to do with a txt file? And what exactly is the problem you are having

Comment: As a small unrelated tip, it's probably a good idea to store your pins as `String` rather than `int`. If you store them as ints, the pins `0001` and `1` are considered to be identical.

Comment: how A and hashpin will be equal? Also where are you specifying to Scanner object that you will read from file?

Comment: You're just declaring the file but you actually read from the standard input instead

Comment: You're just declaring the file but you actually read from the standard input instead

Comment: `File balances = new File("Balances.txt");` and what's next with file's content?

Comment: As @VivekMangal said, A and hashpin cannot be equal because hashpin is an integer between 0 and 63.